# add hover & focus to checkbox - React

Tags: css, reactjs

I need to show the effects when hovering or focus the checkbox. Added focus & hover functions too. but these are not visible. following is my CSS & code
I have added those but things don't work. 1st image is checked A2 & 2nd image is both unchecked. Thanks in advance

[image: checked A2]
[image: unchecked A1 & A2]

**Code**

```
<div className='myclass'>
    <div className='checkbox-container'>
    <input id='a1' type='checkbox' checked={checked} onChange={handleChecked} 
    className={'my-custom-input-label-box'}/>
    <label htmlFor='a1' className='btn'>A1</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myclass{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  
}

.checkbox-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  }

  input[type="checkbox"]{
    display:flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: url(./img/barStool.png);
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: content-box ;
    width: 50px;
    height: 70px;
    border-width: 0;
    transition: all .3s linear;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
      background-color: #2ECC71;
      top: 6;
      background: url(./img/seat.png);
      background-size: cover;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"]:focus{
      outline: 0 none;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] + label.btn :hover{
      box-shadow: 0 4px #ab3c3c;
      top: 2px;
      background-color: #4b15e0;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

removed the following attribute from the CSS file
**+ label.btn**

```
input[type=checkbox]:hover{
          top: 2px;
    }
```